# Print only unique lines that appear last in logfile based on date/time

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I'm working with a logfile with the following format:

```
Oct 12 01:28:26 server program: 192.168.1.105 text for 1.105 
Oct 12 01:30:00 server program: 192.168.1.104 text for 1.104 
Oct 12 01:30:23 server program: 192.168.1.103 text for 1.103
Oct 12 01:32:39 server program: 192.168.1.101 text for 1.101 
Oct 12 02:28:26 server program: 192.168.1.105 text for 1.105 
Oct 12 02:30:00 server program: 192.168.1.104 text for 1.104
Oct 12 02:30:23 server program: 192.168.1.103 text for 1.103 
Oct 12 02:32:39 server program: 192.168.1.101 text for 1.101
```

I need to achieve this:

```
Oct 12 02:28:26 server program: 192.168.1.105 text for 1.105 
Oct 12 02:30:00 server program: 192.168.1.104 text for 1.104
Oct 12 02:30:23 server program: 192.168.1.103 text for 1.103
Oct 12 02:32:39 server program: 192.168.1.101 text for 1.101
```

How can I send the new output to a file? I have tried this:

```
awk '!_[$6]++ {a=$6} END{print a}' logfile
```

But it does not give me the results expected. How can I use awk or sed to give me only the unique lines with last time the string match was seen or based on date/time?

Comment: Can you edit your example to include multiple different programs and multiple different messages for the same program on the same server, so I can see in your expected output how you want to handle those?  Or is there only one program per server?  (You can make up server and program names—use fruits or whatever—but when the example data is all monotonous it makes it hard to understand your actual use case.)

Comment: both server and program will always be the same. The messages after the IP will only be different if the IP is different.

Comment: I made some updates.

Comment: @don_crissti, simple as it is, that is a very good Answer.  ;)

Comment: @don_crissti, *"it can be done without* any *sorting"*, yes, but not with my approach (since `uniq` requires input to be sorted and I'm ignoring the timestamp), and AFAIK Awk arrays do not guarantee sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to do a second pass (which you pretty well have to), you may as well only store line numbers rather than full records.  It makes the logic easier.

```
awk 'NR == FNR {if (z[$6]) y[z[$6]]; z[$6] = FNR; next} !(FNR in y)' logfile logfile
```

---

**Proof of correctness:**

At the end of processing each line, every line number processed so far is *either* a value in `z`, *or* an index (not value) in `y`, but never both.

The lines represented by values in `z` are, at the end of each iteration, exactly and only the latest records so far seen for each IP address.

The indices of `y` are, therefore, the exact lines which we wish *not* to print.

Comment: Similar concept in one pass: `awk 'p[$6]{delete k[p[$6]]}{p[$6]=NR;k[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(i in k)print k[i]}' logfile` . (k=keep; p=posn_to_delete) With GNU awk can use `END{PROC_INFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for(i in k)print k[i]}`

Answer (score 3):

Save the entire line (using `$6` as array index) and in `END` iterate over the elements of the array:

```
awk '{z[$6]=$0};END{for (i in z) print z[i]}' logfile
```

The result won't be sorted though... You could do something like:

```
awk '{z[$6]=NR" "$0};END{for (i in z) print z[i]}' logfile | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2-
### this space ^ is a literal TAB
```

which saves the line no. plus the line content to be able to then sort by line no.

---

Other ways involve a 2nd pass to get it sorted by date (since this is a log) but will print duplicate entries if the input contains duplicate lines (entire lines, that is) - e.g. with `grep`:

```
awk '{z[$6]=$0};END{for (var in z) print z[var]}' logfile | grep -Fxf- logfile
```

or only with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{z[$6]=$0;next}
FNR==1{for (var in z) y[z[var]]}
$0 in y' logfile logfile
```

Comment: Nice idea, using Awk for two passes.  :)  If you're going to do that, though, you don't even need to store lines.  I decided to post the [alternate approach](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320950/135943) as an answer rather than a comment since the explanation was a bit long.

Comment: Don, I noticed that for some reason your command is leaving some duplicates. If you run your command and re-direct to a new file the do something like "grep program | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | less" you will hopefully see what I'm talking about.

Comment: record-keeping purposes. You can still see the anomaly when not re-directing its just easier that way for me to verify that there were no duplicates. I did not mean to imply that a re-direct was a possible cause of the results I was seeing.

Comment: @user53029 - you do realise I don't have access to your data so I can't replicate whatever happens on your side hence I _cannot_ see any anomaly (I don't see how the solutions above could print duplicate entries anyway - it's impossible "by design" - unless you have _duplicate lines_ like in, entire lines) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have lines only from the same day you can handle this like so:

```
sort -k6 -k3r logfile | uniq -f3 | sort -k3
```

If you have lines for more than one day you can still use this basic approach, but your sorting will have to get a lot fancier.  The above command can only handle one day's records because it uses the time portion of the timestamp (e.g. `02:28:26`) as a proxy for the entire timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Logic becomes simpler by reversing the file linewise

```
$ tac logfile | awk '!seen[$6]++' | tac
Oct 12 02:28:26 server program: 192.168.1.105 text for 1.105 
Oct 12 02:30:00 server program: 192.168.1.104 text for 1.104
Oct 12 02:30:23 server program: 192.168.1.103 text for 1.103 
Oct 12 02:32:39 server program: 192.168.1.101 text for 1.101
```